# Guidance for Python logic programming

Tags: python, logic

I am having difficulty figuring out how to go about coding a simple logic program to calculate pendulum movement. See [this doc](http://www.XboxFlashing.com/cw2010.pdf), I am stuck on task two.

What I have so far is:

- Defined variables
- Raw_input for variables
- Code pasted from the PDF.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to go on since I have very limited experience with Python.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "logic programming": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I won't give you a complete answer - I'll just give some hints.

The question asks you to reduce the timestep. To do this change this line:

```
dt = 0.1 # Use a smaller value.
```

It then asks you to verify that the period and amplitude of the oscillation are correct. The simplest way to do this is to print the results out to the screen or a file and verify them manually. This requires little-to-no programming ability and can be done in just a few minutes.

Alternatively you can calculate the period and amplitude programatically by finding the local maximum of the angle. To do this search for every occurrence of three values such that the middle one is greater than the two on either side. I would suggest writing this is a separate function - possibly as a generator (using yield). The time between two local maximums is the period.